# Why does $f'(x)\neq 0 \iff f: 1-1$ graphically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So, we know that $f'(x)\neq 0 \iff f: 1-1$ .To prove this algebraically, we use proof by contradiction by letting $x_{1} \neq x_{2}$ equal $f(x_{1})=f(x_{2})$, and via Rolle's Theorum we end up with $f'(x)=0$, which contradicts with our starting hypothesis that $f'(x)\neq 0.$ Is there a way to prove this graphically? I mean, if $f'(x_{0})=0,$ we just know that on $x_{0}$ the tangent line of $f$ is parallex to the x'x axis, how can we reach so far to say that $f: 1-1$, if only $f'(x)\neq 0$ ? Sorry if it's diffucult to understand what I'm asking, but I having difficulty wrap by mind around it.

EDIT: To use Rolle's Theorum we accept that f is continuous on [a,b] and differentiable on (a,b), where [a,b] is a subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Surely you must have more conditions on $f$ than that... such as at requiring $f$ to have a continuous derivative.  Otherwise, consider $|x|$ which is clearly not injective since $|-1|=|1|$ despite $-1\neq 1$

Comment: It's not true that $f'(x)\neq0\iff f\text{ is one to one}$.  Consider for example $f(x)=x^3$. It has $f'(0)=0$, yet it is one to one. Instead, it is correct that $f'(x)\neq0\implies f\text{ is one to one}$ (assuming it is a function that is differentiable on all of $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: To use Rolle's Theorum we accept that f is continuous on [a,b] and differentiable on (a,b), where [a,b] is a subset of R. Does that help though?

Comment: I feel like [tag:algebra-precalculus] isn't an appropriate tag here, although I'm not sure what it should be replaced with. [tag:real-analysis]?